# Select one column in a list without where condition using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of projects, i want to select the projectname from the first list without any condition.

for example

```
List<Project> p = new List<Project>();
Project pro = new Project();
pro.Name = "xxx";
pro.Code ="111";
p.Add(pro);

Project pro = new Project();
pro.Name = "yyy";
pro.Code ="112";
p.Add(pro);
```

Here by default i want to select the projectcode 111 without any condition from linq is it possible?

I have an idea how to take the project code with condition

```
var proj = (from pn in pro where pro.Name= "xxx" select pn.Code);
```

I dont want to put any where condition i want the first project code using linq, anybody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: ya, i am sorry, i searched with all possible combination i didnt get any result for my query. So i posted here

Comment: It happens. When you know how to formulate the question duplicates are easy to find, but otherwise any search can be quite frustrating. It is easy in a language or technology you know, but much more difficult with new and unknown one. Just try to use synonyms or other phrasings more extensively during your next search. Also distance yourself from the object domain while searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.100).aspx). This Linq method will return the first element in a sequence.

```
var firstElement =  p.First();
```

`.First()` will throw an exception if there's no row to be returned, while `.FirstOrDefault()` will return a default value instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I need to wait 6 more minutes for click answered :-)

Comment: Typo: FirstOfDefault, its FirstOrDefault. Tried editng it, but can't.. it needs min 6 chars edit ;)

Comment: @pryashrma Thanks, updated.